# spx to be modified for a duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following procedure and its working, my knowledge to spx is limited and i am trying to add a check for duplicate inserts

how can i do it any guidance please

i want to do it for all my tables except date fields which differe, but i think once i get the starting point, it will be easier

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_schedule_insert  
   @_scheduleid int  OUTPUT,
   @_schedule nvarchar(max)
AS 
   BEGIN

      SET  XACT_ABORT  ON

      SET  NOCOUNT  ON

      SET @_scheduleid = NULL

      INSERT dbo.schedule(schedule)
         VALUES (@_schedule)

      SELECT @_scheduleid = scope_identity()

   END
```

mysql seems to have something onduplicatecheck, does sqlserver has something like this, i am on 2017 sql

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired result.  What do you mean by "duplicate insert".

Comment: like, i inserted Monday in one record, i should not be able to inserted Monday again, but if there is one more record like Monday in one case and Monday, Tuesday in other case, it will let insert, its just not the exact same duplicate should be inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `schedule` to never be duplicated, then add a unique constraint:

```
alter table dbo.schedule add constraint unq_schedule_schedule
    unique (schedule);
```

Any attempt to insert or update two schedules so they have the same value will result in an error.

This is a *data integrity* issue.  The database should check that there are no duplicates, if that is your intention.